# How does this code extract arguments from tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

So I've been confronted to the issue of storing variadic arguments in a tuple in order to invoke a function later with these. I found an answer by [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) which does this very nicely, but I fail to understand what it exactly does. Here's the code:

```
// implementation details, users never invoke these directly
namespace detail
{
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N>
    struct call_impl
    {
        static void call(F f, Tuple && t)
        {
            call_impl<F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...(N), Total, N..., sizeof...(N)>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
        }
    };

    template <typename F, typename Tuple, int Total, int... N>
    struct call_impl<F, Tuple, true, Total, N...>
    {
        static void call(F f, Tuple && t)
        {
            f(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
        }
    };
}

// user invokes this
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
void call(F f, Tuple && t)
{
    typedef typename std::decay<Tuple>::type ttype;
    detail::call_impl<F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size<ttype>::value, std::tuple_size<ttype>::value>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

Basically, the part that bogs me is the following one:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N>
    struct call_impl
    {
        static void call(F f, Tuple && t)
        {
            call_impl<F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...(N), Total, N..., sizeof...(N)>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
        }
    };
```

I understand there's some sort of TMP recursion with the `N...` and `sizeof...(N)`, that stops with the partial specialization that has `Done` set to `true`, which happens when the condition `Total == 1 + sizeof...(N)` is verified.

What I can't understand is where this `N...` comes from. I can't see where it starts...

Could someone explain how this implementation works? (if that's not off topic for SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First invocation:

```
typedef typename std::decay<Tuple>::type ttype;
detail::call_impl<
  F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size<ttype>::value, std::tuple_size<ttype>::value
>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
```

Note they pass 4 arguments to `call_impl`.

```
<typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N>
struct call_impl
```

here you can see it takes 4 arguments, then `int...`.  `int...` means "zero or more `int`s".  So it starts with zero `int`s.

But `Done` is false unless the `ttype` is empty.

If `Done` is false, the base instance is used:

```
call_impl<F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...(N), Total, N..., sizeof...(N)>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
```

initially `N...` is empty, so `sizeof...(N)` is `0`.  This this ends up with

```
call_impl<F, Tuple, Total == 1 + 0, Total, 0>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
```

which populates `N...` with `0`.  `Done` is set to true iff `Total==1`.  If not, we recurse, and end up setting `N...` to `0,1`, repeating until `Done`.  Once `Done` is true, we have an `N...` that is populated with `0, 1, 2,` ... up to `Total-1`.

`Done` being true causes this specialization to be invoked:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, int Total, int... N>
struct call_impl<F, Tuple, true, Total, N...>
```

which does the call.

Now, this is a strange and awkward way to do a technique where you build up that sequence based off `Total`, then pass a type containing that sequence to a function as an argument, and deduce the sequence out of the type.  But the above technique works.

Comment: Oh snap! I totally forgot that the `int... N` could actually be empty and that the recursion could start from there. Thanks!